# R - Amending a Daylight Savings issue in interval data

Tags: r, time, series, dst

I am looking at some electricity load data and ran into a DST issue.  The data look like:

```
Acct        date          hour  usage
198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    0   8976
198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    1   6912
198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    3   9024
198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    4   8976
198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    5   8928
198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    6   8976
...
260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    0   12710.4
260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    1   9364.8
260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    3   15556.8
260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    4   12628.8
260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    5   12619.2
260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    6   13051.2
260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    7   12907.2
260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    8   12835.2
...
```

As you can see, on this date DST went into effect, thus skipping hour 2 and leaving me with 23 data points per day instead of 24.  I hope to rectify this by including the missing hour with an average usage value of the previous (hour 1) and next (hour 3) hours usage.

E.g. for the first Acct, I'd like to have:

```
Acct        date          hour  usage
198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    0   8976
198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    1   6912
198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    2   7968
198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z    3   9024
```

I'm posting here as I'm having trouble finding an efficient way to do this for all Accounts (there are about 500).  Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Acct, date) %>%
 complete(hour = seq(min(hour), max(hour), 1)) %>%
 mutate(usage = if_else(is.na(usage), (lag(usage) + lead(usage))/2, usage))

   Acct date                  hour  usage
   <int> <chr>                <dbl>  <dbl>
 1   198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     0  8976 
 2   198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     1  6912 
 3   198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     2  7968 
 4   198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     3  9024 
 5   198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     4  8976 
 6   198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     5  8928 
 7   198 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     6  8976 
 8   260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     0 12710.
 9   260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     1  9365.
10   260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     2 12461.
11   260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     3 15557.
12   260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     4 12629.
13   260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     5 12619.
14   260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     6 13051.
15   260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     7 12907.
16   260 2018-03-11T00:00:00Z     8 12835.
```

Comment: Brilliant, much appreciated